# How to resolve error "The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While starting Spring Boot Application I am getting this error:

```
The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
        - org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration
```

This is how my application looks like. I have excluded `WebsecurityConfiguration.class` from `EnablEAutoConfiguration` but I keep on getting the above error. If I remove `WebsecurityConfiguration.class` from exclude my application is not able to get properties from `application.yaml`. Can you please help me in resolving this issue?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfiguration.class

})
// @ComponentScan("com.infy.ceh.management")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.infy.ceh.management", excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, value = {
        ExcludeAnnotationFilter.class })

)
public class AgentApplication {

}
```

Answer (score 16):

In the entry point for your SpringBoot app, use the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={@ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=<classThatYouWantToExclued>.class)})
public class TestApplication {
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `WebSecurityConfiguration` is not an auto-configuration class, but you are excluding it in the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` section. I would remove the class from `EnableAutoConfiguration` and filter it with `@ComponentScan` and `ExcludeAnnotationFilter` instead.